# Can I use "system logs" in knowing and fixing any errors?

Tags: 17.10, system, error-handling, iwlwifi, logs

As you might guess I'm still brand new around linux and I've started my journey 10 days ago with Ubuntu 16.04 and have upgraded till I reached Ubuntu 17.10.  I'm very nervous because I'm afraid that one day I might switch the PC on to find some black screen staring back at me and blocking my way to my files and the internet.  So, I'm trying to educate myself as much as possible to preempt any disasters. Today I came upon something called "System Logs" when I opened it I found a hell lot of messages (looks like errors) and some of them are listed as important.  My question: is there a way I can use this to detect and solve any problems?  Thanks.

P.S.: I know I'm having a problem with my wifi connection which is acting like a yoyo; one minute up and one minute down.  At least this is one problem I know of.

This is what I get from the "dmesg" command:

```
[15990.659912] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[15990.660059] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[15990.660064] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Status: 0x00000200, count: 6
[15990.660067] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 29.541020.0
[15990.660072] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000019C2 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[15990.660075] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000002A0 | trm_hw_status0
[15990.660078] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[15990.660081] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00043D58 | branchlink2
[15990.660084] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0004B016 | interruptlink1
[15990.660087] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | interruptlink2
[15990.660091] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | data1
[15990.660093] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | data2
[15990.660096] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | data3
[15990.660100] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x488000F3 | beacon time
[15990.660102] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x1703DD11 | tsf low
[15990.660105] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000005 | tsf hi
[15990.660108] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[15990.660112] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0259E583 | time gp2
[15990.660115] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[15990.660118] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001D | uCode version major
[15990.660121] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0008415C | uCode version minor
[15990.660124] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000210 | hw version
[15990.660127] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00C89200 | board version
[15990.660130] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000001C | hcmd
[15990.660133] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x24022000 | isr0
[15990.660136] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00881800 | isr1
[15990.660139] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[15990.660142] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x40415CC0 | isr3
[15990.660144] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[15990.660148] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x0A9E001C | last cmd Id
[15990.660151] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[15990.660154] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x000000D4 | l2p_control
[15990.660157] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00018020 | l2p_duration
[15990.660160] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000007 | l2p_mhvalid
[15990.660163] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000081 | l2p_addr_match
[15990.660166] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00000005 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[15990.660169] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x15061956 | timestamp
[15990.660172] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: 0x00006878 | flow_handler
[15990.660178] ieee80211 phy1: Hardware restart was requested
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to the Linux world!

Yes, that is what the system logs are for;

- Logging normal behavior
- Warning about issues
- Output software / hardware errors, as (if) they occur.

An example of normal healthy output from startup logging:

> ```
> [   15.176458] e1000: eth1 NIC Link is Up 100 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
> [   15.176779] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
> [   15.177032] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
> ```

An example (taken from https://serverfault.com/questions/407007/what-do-these-disk-errors-in-syslog-mean) about bad sectors on disk:

> sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto
>   reallocate failed

Both of these examples are from [dmesg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/dmesg.1.html),

```
$ dmesg
```

The suggested solution to your problem, as stated in bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1710390, is to do the following,

In a terminal, open the NetworkManager.conf

```
$ nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf <-- nano is a text-editor for novices.
```

add the following,

```
[device] wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no.
```

Save the file, and perhaps restart the network manager,

```
$ sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: Can u pls tell me how to copy the information that I have in my log so I can show it to you?  Do I just copy/paste it?

Comment: All I know is that one minute the wifi is up and working and one minute it is down... It keeps like this the whole day.  At first I thought the internet was faulty but I noticed that my other devices are working just fine.  Everything was just fine before I upgraded to 17.10.

Comment: Yes, just edit your question and add any log output you may think is of interest. I suggest start with `dmesg`.

Comment: Ok I got a whole bunch of lines so I copied for you the last part (which had many red lines in it), up in my main question.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1710390 might be related. They suggest the following workaround: In `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, add [device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no.

Comment: This is too technical for me to understand!  Can u pls explain in detail like yr explaining to a 5-year old :-))  I'm very ignorant, sorry.  Still crawling compared to you.

Comment: @NermeenHussein I edited my answer to try and explain how to achieve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "In a terminal, open the NetworkManager.conf"? How do I do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69648/discussion-between-nermeen-hussein-and-mattias).